# DT - Cannot use class argument in datatable()

Tags: r

The class argument seems not to be considered..
Even in very basic examples:

```
 library(DT)
 datatable(iris)
```

the datatable has no style attached:
[image: dt]

See expected output [here](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/)
Am I doing something wrong or is it normal?

Thank you in advance for your help on this issue!

Regards

ps: I'm using DT Version 0.0.11

[EDIT]

There is the following workaround, but is it the best way to proceed? Many thanks in advance!

```
library(DT)
library(htmltools) 
datatable(
  data = iris,
  container = tags$table(
    class="stripe row-border",
    tags$thead(tags$tr(lapply(colnames(iris), tags$th)))
  )
)
```

[image: dt2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your packages (as mentioned on top of the link that you provided yourself ;-) ):

```
# [1] DT_0.0.38
# [1] htmlwidgets_0.3.3

devtools::install_github('ramnathv/htmlwidgets')
devtools::install_github("rstudio/DT")
```

Then, this will work:

```
library(DT)
datatable(head(iris), class = 'cell-border stripe')
```